# Jenkins and Xcode5 unit test target - no test output?

Tags: ios, xcode, jenkins, xcodebuild, xcode5

I am upgrading a Jenkins CI server from XCode 4.6 to XCode 5 and iOS SDK 7.

To run unit tests, I must now use `xcodebuild test`. I am piping the output of this command to a Ruby script, that generates test reports.

This does not work any longer after the upgrade. I think the problem lies in the fact that `xcodebuild test` launches a new process to actually run the tests. The last statement in my log is

```
/bin/sh -c /Volumes/Data/Jenkins/jobs/MyProject-Unit/workspace/Build/Intermediates/Redacted.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/UnitTests.build/Script-261C7EA912FD9A4B00F7A53E.sh
```

The output after that point can not be found in the Jenkins log, but when I run it on my own machine, I get the test results printed in the console.

What is happening here, and how can I get the test reports back ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm on the same trail. I believe if you look into that script, it will turn around and call this script:

`${SYSTEM_DEVELOPER_DIR}/Tools/RunUnitTests`

This is script that used to run unit tests. Now, in Xcode 5, it just tells you to remove the Run Script build phase that Xcode 4 automatically creates. If you run `RunUnitTests` from Xcode 5, it just says:

> RunUnitTests is obsolete. To run unit tests for your target, use the
>   Test scheme action in the Xcode IDE and the test action in xcodebuild.
>   You can remove the Run Script build phase that invokes RunUnitTests
>   from your unit test bundle target.

I've gone ahead and done what it says (removed the Run Script phase) and I still get no output under Jenkins, perhaps because, as you surmise, it's a new process, and Jenkins sees the first process complete, and jumps out.

Update: More info here: [How can I get Xcode 5 to run iOS unit tests on a Jenkins slave?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18921078/how-can-i-get-xcode-5-to-run-ios-unit-tests-on-a-jenkins-slave)