# xcodebuild corrupts test result output when output redirected to file

Tags: xcode, unit-testing, pipe, xcode5, xcodebuild

I have Jenkins with the Xcode plugin configured to run unit tests by adding the test build action to the Custom xcodebuild arguments setting. For more information on getting Jenkins to run the unit tests at all with Xcode 5, see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18921078/10223).

Now that I have it running, it seems to mix console output from NSLog statements or the final `** TEST SUCCEEDED **` message with the test results, thus occasionally tripping up the parser that converts unit test results to the JUnit format required for Jenkins.

For example, the Jenkins log shows output like this:

```
Test Case '-[Redacted_Conversion_Tests testConvertTo_ShouldSetamount_WhenamountIsNotZero]' passed (** TEST SUCCEEDED **

0.000 seconds).
Test Case '-[Redacted_Conversion_Tests testConvertTo_ShouldSetamount_WhenamountIsZero]' started.
```

when it should actually be:

```
Test Case '-[Redacted_Conversion_Tests testConvertTo_ShouldSetamount_WhenamountIsNotZero]' passed (0.000 seconds).
Test Case '-[Redacted_Conversion_Tests testConvertTo_ShouldSetamount_WhenamountIsZero]' started.
** TEST SUCCEEDED **
```

I have looked into this further and pulled Jenkins out of the picture. If I run the xcodebuild command directly at the command prompt:

```
xcodebuild \
    -workspace project.xcworkspace \
    -scheme Tests \
    -configuration Release \
    -sdk iphonesimulator7.0 \
    -destination "platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone Retina (4-inch),OS=latest" \
    test
```

the output always comes out fine, in-order.

If, however, I pipe the output to another program or redirect to a file:

```
xcodebuild \
    -workspace project.xcworkspace \
    -scheme Tests \
    -configuration Release \
    -sdk iphonesimulator7.0 \
    -destination "platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone Retina (4-inch),OS=latest" \
    test > xcodebuild.out
cat xcodebuild.out
```

The output is out-of-order as described above.

Could this be due to buffering or lack of buffering when not directly writing to stdout? Does anyone know why this is happening and any workaround I might be able to perform to fix it?

Comment: What parser do you use to change the output to junit test results?

Comment: [OCUnit2JUnit](https://github.com/ciryon/OCUnit2JUnit)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Thanks to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11349234/10223), I discovered a way to essentially disable buffering using the `script` command.

```
script -q -t 0 xcodebuild.out \
    xcodebuild \
        -workspace project.xcworkspace \
        -scheme Tests \
        -configuration Release \
        -sdk iphonesimulator7.0 \
        -destination "platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone Retina (4-inch),OS=latest" \
        test
cat xcodebuild.out
```

Comment: if you are piping to another command *cough* ocunit2junit *cough* then 
```
script -q /dev/null xcodebuild ... | ocunit2junit
```
will work

Comment: Late to the game, but another way to do this is with `env NSUnbufferedIO=YES xcodebuild ...`. Tested on Yosemite and Xcode 7.

Answer (score 13):

As noted by [Malte](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1143003/malte-tancred) in a comment above, a cleaner solution might be

```
    env NSUnbufferedIO=YES xcodebuild ...
```

Comment: That is the real solution